# Delete rights on Custom List (No Code)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions

I have created a custom list with 3 below columns.

```
Name(Single line of text) 
Approved(Radio Yes/No) 
Comments(Multiple line of text)
```

I have given users the contributor rights on this list. Once the item is created I want to give users delete rights on created item only when the value in Approved field is No. Users should not be able to delete the item when Approve is selected as Yes. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a workflow to your list using SharePoint Designer, you can add an Impersonation Step. Then you can use a set of Workflow Actions for Add/Remove/Replace permissions on list items.

[image]

Comment: Thanks..but in the edit workflow section of SP designer i am not able to find actions to perform such changes in the list item. Please help.

Comment: Edited with picture